# метод File.Create

Tags: c#

Вот конструкция для сохранения текущего состояния программы:

```
Model model = new Model();
FileStream fs = File.Create("save.dat");
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(fs, model);
fs.Close();
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при сохранении происходила не перезапись существующего файла, а новое сохранение? На MSDN нашел только вариант с переопределением места сохранения.

Answer (score 3):

КО сообщает: для того, чтобы сохранять данные в новое место, надо давать файлу новое имя

Comment: вопрос и был задан с целью узнать, как давать имя файлу и делать очередное сохранение. например, пользователь нажимает на кнопку и появляется окно, где предлагается ввести имя файла и директорию сохранения. у меня, пока, при нажатии происходит сохранение с перезаписью.

Comment: @cruim ну так и задавайте вопрос про запрос имени файла! А лучше - погуглите, примеров в сети - туча! Зачем вы спрашиваете про метод File.Create, как будто проблема именно в нем?

Answer (score 0):

1. Создавать другой файл. Это самый логичный вариант. Я бы использовал дату в формате `yyyy_MM_dd HH_mm_ss` как часть его имени.
2. Просто открывать файл для добавления в конец. Записать проста, а как потом читать определённый кусок - надо думать.
3. Использовать альтернативные файловые потоки. Об их поддержке .net'ом мне неизвестно, т. е. вполне возможно, что придётся использовать winapi. Да и вообще, не рекомендую, ибо альтернативные потоки могут потеряться при копировании.